# Grouping Alarms in Android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

In my project, I have to set multiple alarms for a single TV show, I want to group these alarms according to the show's name, so that while deleting these alarms I just want to have show's name.... Is it possible?

Thanks in Advance... !

Comment: If have not much experience with this but couldn't you just set 1 alarm en when that is triggered set a new alarm?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code for starting an activity after the minutes defined from current time.

```
            Intent i = new Intent(this, launch_alarm.class); // Create Intent
            i.putExtra("id", id); // pass show id here, and get it from the activity you started. There you can grab the show schedule using id from database or anything you want to do with id
            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, id, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT); // Create pending intent with a unique id and pass intent as a paramenter
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            int secs = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
            secs = 60-secs;
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            day = day*24;
            hr = hr+day;
            hr = hr*60;
            min = min+hr;
            min--;
            calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, min); // Set time time in calendar variable, in this case first system time is set on calendar variable, than the minutes are added that after how many minutes you want intent to start.
            calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, secs);
            am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pi); // pass calendar variable and pending activity.
```

for further refrence, check this link
http://learnandroideasily.blogspot.com/2013/05/android-alarm-manager_31.html

Comment: this is the code from my project, let me know if the answer satisfies you, or you have any further queries :)